# Complex equation of any line

Tags: complex-numbers

**In my book it is given**[image]

I could not understand how they have written the statement given in **NOTE**.

Comment: It's about rotation of a curve.

Comment: @MyGlasses how .

Comment: We can rotate every point $z$ (as a vector) with an angle $\theta$, not only in a line, but in every equation, $f(ze^{i\theta})$ is a rotation of $f(z)$.

Comment: @MyGlasses this is valid for every equation

Comment: Of course. If change $z$ by $ze^{i\theta}$ we rotate every point about origin with angle $\theta$, other case, If we change $f(z)$ to  $e^{i\theta}f(z)$ then we rotate whole of shape  with angle $\theta$.

Comment: @MyGlasses $\theta$ is taken from where ? For a line rotating it , we have to multipy all its equation with $e^{i\theta}$ ,but as above in my book it is only given that replace z with z$e^{i\theta}$.

Comment: As I said above, we can replace $z$ with $ze^{i\theta}$ and this angle is **arbitrary**. Also In line, we replace $z$ with $ze^{i\theta}$ and then replace $\overline{z}$ with $\overline{z}e^{-i\theta}$ for rotation.

Comment: @MyGlasses If we want to rotate it about any other point(not the origin) ,then how can we do it .

Answer (score 1):

Hint: divide by $|\alpha|^2 = \alpha \bar \alpha\ne 0$ and write equation as:

$$
\frac{z}{\alpha}+\frac{\bar z}{\bar \alpha} + \frac{r}{|\alpha|^2} = 0 \quad\iff\quad \operatorname{Re}\left(\frac{z}{\alpha}\right) = - \,\frac{r}{2\,|\alpha|^2}
$$

The latter means that $\frac{z}{\alpha}$ describes the vertical line passing through $z_0 = - \,\frac{r}{2\,|\alpha|^2}\,$, which in turn means that $z$ describes the line through $\alpha \,z_0$ at angle $\frac{\pi}{2} + \arg(\alpha)\,$.

Replacing $z$ by $z\,e^{i \theta}$ is algebraically equivalent with replacing $\alpha$ by $\alpha \overline{e^{i \theta}} = \alpha e^{-i \theta}\,$, so the angle of the resulting line becomes $\frac{\pi}{2} + \arg(\alpha) - \theta\,$, which is at an angle of $\theta$ with the original line.